# AWS - 404 Not Found - NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

So I have my Web Application deployed onto AWS. All my services and clients are deployed using Fargate, so I build a Docker Image and push that up.

Dockerfile

```
# build environment
FROM node:9.6.1 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I also created a DNS on AWS using Route53 that I pointed to my Load Balancer which is connected to my client application. These have an SSL certificate attached.

**Example DNS**

```
*.test.co.uk
test.co.uk
```

When I navigate to the login page of the application, everything works fine, I can navigate around the application. If I try to navigate straight to /dashboard, I receive a 404 Not Found NGINX error.

Example

```
www.test.co.uk (WORKS FINE)
www.test.co.uk/dashboard (404 NOT FOUND)
```

Is there something I need to configure, either in the Dockerfile or AWS that will allow users to directly navigate to any path?